# How to discourage direction changes with AStar

Tags: path-finding, a-star, game-development, godot, gdscript

Can I make the builtin [`AStar`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_astar.html#class-astar-add-point) choose the shortest path with the **least direction changes**?

I currently build my graph like so:

```
extends GridMap

var _astar = AStar.new()

func _ready():
    var id = 0
    for c in get_used_cells():
        var weight = 1.0
        if _get_cover(c.x, c.y, c.z):
            weight = 9999.0 # impassable tile
        _astar.add_point(id, Vector3(c.x, c.y, c.z), weight)
        id += 1

    for c in get_used_cells():
        var center = _astar.get_closest_point(Vector3(c.x, c.y, c.z))
        var above = _astar.get_closest_point(Vector3(c.x, c.y, c.z + 1))
        var right = _astar.get_closest_point(Vector3(c.x + 1, c.y, c.z))
        assert(id > 0)
        if above >= 0:
            _astar.connect_points(center, above, true)
        if right >= 0:
            _astar.connect_points(center, right, true)
```

It seems like you can only weight points, not edges, so I'm not sure how to prefer one direction over another.
The path it chooses always seems to maximize direction changes:

[image: jagged path]

Answer (score 0):

When you see 3 Nodes, if the direction is changed, then **increase the F value of last Node**.

[Three Nodes will tell you that the direction changes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H9yF.png)